# AdMob Rewarded Video Ads always shows same ad

Tags: ios, advertisements, admob

I have integrated **AdMob rewarded video ads** in my iOS game. Currently, the game is in development stage and not released on the store. Currently, the **fill rate** is around **30%-40%** and I always see the same rewarded video ad. I have following questions:

1. Why the fill rate is such low? I am testing the game in India and the US.
2. Why the game is receiving the same ad from AdMob? Are there any settings that can allow different ads from the network?

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you

**More information:**

The **test ads** gives 95%-98% fill rate. Hence, I think there is no problem with the AdMob SDK configuration. Previously, I tried using **AdMob mediation** and the ads were coming other ads networks (**NO ADS FROM ADMOB**).

Is there a AdMob policy where they don't provide enough ads to "under development" game/application?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever ad is being served is irrelevant to you as the app developer. You get paid just the same. However, you should generally be seeing a higher fill rate than that. While in development you should be using test ads anyway, though. This involves either using a test ad point or registering specific devices as test devices.

See here:

https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads

If you get the same fill rate with test ads, there is likely an issue with communication to the AdMob servers. If, on the other hand, you get a much higher fill rate with test ads, AdMob may simply not have sufficient inventory for your app. Your best bet in this case is to use AdMob mediation to allow other ad networks to pick up the slack to get you that high fill rate.

https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/mediation/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The test ads gives 95%-98% fill rate. Hence, I think there is no problem with the AdMob SDK configuration. Previously, I tried using AdMob mediation and the ads were coming other ads networks (NO ADS FROM ADMOB). Is there a AdMob policy where they don't provide enough ads to "under development" game/application?

Comment: There’s not an explicit policy laid out like that, but they generally don’t fill ad requests as readily to an audience which is highly unlikely to click on an ad, which is generally the case for small audiences (eg just the developer(s)). Once there’s a larger audience it may fill up. As for not getting AdMob ads, it sounds like mediation is working correctly, given that you were seeing a low fill rate otherwise. The more mediated networks competing to fill your ad request the better, generally. Just make sure your automatic eCPM fetching is working for each network in AdMob’s mediation setup.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. After the game is released on the store, will the fill rate improve even if I have small audience playing the game?

Comment: It depends on the audience’s behavior, but generally speaking, yes. I would still recommend integrating other ad networks and using mediation though, since if nothing else it will drive up prices for your placements and generally you’ll get paid more.